# Shorten lines where they meet

Tags: qgis

I have one line with multiple features that I split into separate lines based on features. Now, the two lines that have separate features meet since they were one line before. What I want to do now is to make a gap between these two lines of a certain size. Any idea how to do it in QGIS?

See the place where they meet? I need to get a gap there of 10m from each side.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Extract the "meeting point", buffer by 10 m, clip your lines, tada.

Comment: Thx Erik, I have the same logic but implementation is causing problems. :D

Comment: FOUND IT! Thnx. :)

Comment: @Erik, with this workflow, I would suggest using `difference` rather than `clip`, otherwise you end up keeping the line ends, rather than removing them ;)

Comment: Yeah, you know what I mean -.-

Answer (score 10):

You can use a Geometry expression like so:

```
line_substring(
    $geometry, 
    10,
    length($geometry) - 10
)
```

If it is for visualisation purposes only, you can make a Geometry Generator symbol layer:

[image]

###### Result

The thinner line is the original geometry, the thicker overlay is the result of the expression.

[image]

If you need to make a new data layer, you can use the same expression with the *Geometry by Expression* tool.